Error 'FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth-Swift.h' file not found after updating Firebase to 11.5.0 using CocoaPods
I am trying to update Firebase to version 11.5.0 (previously 10.28.1) using CocoaPods.
My current Podfile configuration is as follows:
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

However, I keep encountering the error: 'FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth-Swift.h' file not found.
The error occurs in the Firebase.h file:
#if __has_include(<FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>)
#import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>
#if __has_include("FirebaseAuth-umbrella.h")
  #if __has_include(<UIKit/UIKit.h>)
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #endif
  #import <FirebaseAuthInterop/FIRAuthInterop.h>
  #import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth-Swift.h>
#endif
#endif

This happens no matter what I try, including cleaning the project, running pod deintegrate, or removing the derived data.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

I suggest you try moving to Swift Package management rather than using cocoapods.

I switched to Swift Package Manager for Firebase and project compiles again.
